# How to embed a linux terminal in a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter

I saw from internet that one can embed a terminal into a jupyter notebook cell. In this cell you open up a terminal, and work as a normal terminal you open up in jupyter lab.

Comment: Can not remember, but I copied and paste the example to some notebook I created, but can not find it any longer :(

Comment: This? http://slhogle.github.io/2017/bash_jupyter_notebook/

Comment: No. I just found the solution and paste the answer

Comment: It sounds like you wanted something very specific embedded in your notebook. For others just looking to work with a terminal alongside a notebook, you'll want to check out JupyterLab where you can open a tab with a terminal and place it below or on the side of your notebook pane. You can fully control the dimension and placement with drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
from IPython.display import IFrame
IFrame(‘http://localhost:port/lab1/‘)
```